# Prevent react from restarting the css animation on route change

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

In my react app I have a file called SecondaryLayout.js

```
const SecondaryLayout = ({children, className, ...rest}) => {
    
    return (
        <>
            <Sidebar />
            <main className={['seconday_layout__container', className].join('')} {...rest}>
                {children}
            </main>
        </>
    );
};
```

Sidebar.js:

```
const Sidebar = () => {
    const {user} = useSelector(state => state.auth);
    return (
        <div className="bg-white py-4 px-2 fixed h-screen shadow-lg secondary_layout__sidebar">
            <div className="h-full flex flex-col justify-between items-center">
                <Link to="/"><h1 className="font-pacifico text-white px-2.5 py-1 bg-blue-700 rounded-full text-xl -mb-5">P</h1></Link>
                <div className="flex flex-col space-y-2">
                    <NavLink to="/user/dashboard" className="px-2.5 py-1.5 rounded-lg shadow-md" activeClassName="bg-blue-700 shadow-lg text-white"><TemplateIcon className="inline w-4 h-4 -mt-1"/></NavLink>
                    <NavLink to="/user/listings" className="px-2.5 py-1.5 rounded-lg shadow-md" activeClassName="bg-blue-700 shadow-lg text-white"><ViewListIcon className="inline w-4 h-4 -mt-1"/></NavLink>
                    <NavLink to="/user/address" className="px-2.5 py-1.5 rounded-lg shadow-md" activeClassName="bg-blue-700 shadow-lg text-white"><LocationMarkerIcon className="inline w-4 h-4 -mt-1"/></NavLink>
                    <NavLink to="/user/profile" className="px-2.5 py-1.5 rounded-lg shadow-md" activeClassName="bg-blue-700 shadow-lg text-white"><CogIcon className="inline w-4 h-4 -mt-1"/></NavLink>
                </div>
                <Avatar name={user.username} image={user.image} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

The sidebar has a css animation, and 3 NavLinks, every time I click on a link, the css animation restarts, the behavior that I want is the sidebar to only fade in once, and stay fixed even when I click on a navlink, I tried to wrap my sidebar component with React.memo() but that didn't fix the issue

Edit:
Let's say the user navigates to /user/dashboard, or /user/profile, all these routes should always render the sidebar

Example
Dashboard.js

```
import React from 'react';

import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';

import SecondaryLayout from '../../layouts/SecondaryLayout';

const Dashboard = () => {
    return (
        <SecondaryLayout>
            <Helmet>
                <title>My Dashboard</title>
            </Helmet>
            Dashboard
        </SecondaryLayout>
    );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: What is rendering `SecondaryLayout`? Can you include a more [Complete and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that includes all relevant code? I suspect that `SecondaryLayout` is being remounted.

Comment: The Sidebar and children, so when the user goes to his dashboard (/user/dashboard), I render a Dashboard.js component, whish contains the SecondaryLayout

Comment: Ok, and what is rendering `Dashboard`? The pattern is tracing the component tree back to the component handling the route changes so we can see if there's any obvious rendering issues.

Comment: So the Dashboard is rendering SecondaryLayout whish by itself renders the sidebar and the content of the dashboard

Answer (score 1):

I think I managed to fix the issue, what I was doing is to wrap every component by the secondary layout, what I have done is to move the Secondary Layout to wrap around the route component itself, and not around the component being rendered by the route, i.e: <Route .... /></Route .... />

Comment: Can you share how you were using the `Route` component?

Comment: `<PrivateRoute path="/user/dashboard" component={Dashboard} exact /><PrivateRoute path="/user/profile" component={Profile} exact />`  The **Dashboard** component and the **Profile** component are all wrapped by the SecondaryLayout

Comment: Ok, yeah, that'll do it... remount a new `SecondaryLayout` each time.